Does divergence of a curl vanish in co-ordinate systems with non-orthogonal basis vectors?
In a co-ordinate system with orthonormal basis vectors ( like cartesian co-ordinate system), the divergence of a curl can be written in tensor form as follows to show the expression vanishes:
$$\nabla.\nabla×\vec{A}=\partial_{i}(\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_{j}A_
{k})=\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_{i}\partial_{j}A_
{k}$$
Now as levi-civita tensor is antisymmetric about indices $i$ and $j$ whereas $\partial_{i}\partial_{j}A_{k}$ is symmetric,the expression above vanishes.
But what happens in a co-ordinate system with basis vectors that are not orthogonal?In that case I proceeded in a general way starting with the divergence formula in tensor form (reference form 'Mathematical methods for Physicists by Arfken,7th edition,chapter 4,section 4.3):
$$\nabla.\vec{V}=\frac{1}{[det(g)]^\frac{1}{2}}\partial_{k}([det(g)]^\frac{1}{2}V^k),$$
where g is the metric tensor with co-variant components.
Now if we set $\vec{V}=\nabla×\vec{A},$ then from the above expression we get,
$$\nabla.\nabla×\vec{A}=\frac{1}{[det(g)]^\frac{1}{2}}\partial_{k}([det(g)]^\frac{1}{2}g^{ki}\epsilon_{ijl}\partial_jA_{l})$$
The expression becomes quite complicated indeed,but I can't separate out the symmetric and antisymmetric parts of the expression w.r.t two indices as before(in case of orthonormal basis vectors) to conclude that it vanishes.Does it actually vanish?
Or there are any other ways to prove so?

Divergence and curl are independent of the coordinate system chosen. A quick way to see this is that $$\nabla\cdot A = \mathrm{tr}(DA)$$ where $D$ is the total derivative, and $$\nabla\times A = (\star dA^\flat)^\sharp$$ where $\flat,\sharp$ are the musical isomorphisms, $d$ is the exterior derivative, and $\star$ is the Hodge star.
